# Updating Large Volume of data quickly

Tags: mysql, node.js, algorithm, performance

I have made an application in Nodejs that every minute calls an endpoint and gets a json array that has about 100000 elements. I need to upsert this elements into my database such that if the element doesn't exist I insert it with column "Point" value set to 0.

So far I'm having a cron job and simple upsert query. But it's so slow:

```
 var q = async.queue(function (data, done) {
    db.query('INSERT INTO stat(`user`, `user2`, `point`) '+data.values+' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE point=point+ 10',function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

},100000);

                //Cron job here Every 1 minute execute the lines below:
                var values='' ;
                for (var v=0;v<stats.length;v++) {

                        values = '("JACK","' + stats[v] + '", 0)';
                        q.push({values: values});
                }
```

How can I do such a task in a very short amount of time. Is using mysql a wrong decision? I'm open to any other architecture or solution. Note that I have to do this every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using Bulk Upsert (from [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))! I managed to Upsert over 24k rows in less than 3 seconds. Basically created the query first then ran it:

```
 INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```